# Python how to replace a None value in list with string None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list:

```
test_list = ['one','two',None]
```

Is there any simple way to replace None with 'None' ,without using index, because index for None maybe different each time.

I tried :

```
conv = lambda i : i or 'None'
res = [conv(i) for i in test_list]
```

It works ,is there another way to do so ?

Comment: `res = [ i or 'None' for i in test_list]`

Comment: `['None' if x is None else x for x in test_list]`???

Comment: "It works ,is there another way to do so ?" What precisely about the way you are doing it now is not adequate? Perhaps just drop the pointless `conv = lambda i : i or 'None'` and use that expression in the list comprehension?

Comment: `i or 'None'` can be too broad.  It will turn more than just `None` into a string. `''` and `0` would also be converted to string `'None'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this way all the data types would be converted to string

```
test_list = ['one','two',None]    
res = [str(i) for i in test_list]
```

In this the data type will also be preserved

```
res = ['None' if i is None else i for i in test_list]
```

Comment: `if i == None` -> `if i is None`

Answer (score 0):

The [`opytional` library](https://github.com/mmore500/opytional) expresses this pattern nicely using an interface inspired by C++'s `std::optional`.

```py
>>> import opytional as opyt
>>> test_list = ['one','two', None]
>>> res = [opyt.or_value(x, "None") for x in test_list]
>>> res
['one', 'two', 'None']
```

Installation is available via pip, `python3 -m pip install opytional`.

*Disclaimer*: library author